# JDT Junit Launcher

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-jdt

i try to implement a eclipse plugin, which launch one or many junittest. i've extended my dependecies and plugin.xml. i added an extensions with the point org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts. i already have a plugin with some nice feature a want to add a launch for junit. hier a code:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts">
  <shortcut
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchShortcut"
        icon="icons/images.jpg"
        id="com.emo.plugin.test.SwtPluginTest"
        label="swtshortcutlabel"
        modes="run, debug">
     <contextualLaunch>
        <enablement>
           <with
                 variable="selection">
              <iterate>
                 <adapt
                       type="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaElement">
                    <test
                          property="com.emo.plugin.test.SwtPluginTest"
                          value="junit.framework.Test">
                    </test>
                 </adapt>
              </iterate>
           </with>
        </enablement>
     </contextualLaunch>
     <configurationType
           id="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launchconfig">
     </configurationType>
     <description
           description="swtdebugdescription"
           mode="debug">
     </description>
     <description
           description="swtrundescription"
           mode="run">
     </description>
  </shortcut>
```

can somebody help me?
thank for help

Comment: What's your specific question? Is this code not working?

Comment: Yes, This code doesn't start the Junit Test? How can i create a plugin which launch a junit test? i already have a plugin, i want to add a launcher for junit to this plugin